# How to get the 1 month of tweets using premium twitter api using library tweepy

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, twitterapi-python

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = "NdgcxAtsjUxceCF37rcF5kggL"
consumer_secret = "E0BIhWDpdn0taSl0mdGHNgeWuz2au4NX3Ti1NMAkMu0yh9vrQ5"
access_token = "ACCESS-TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "SECRET-ACCESS -TOKEN"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('FR3.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#adidasfr",count=100,lang="en",from_date="2019-10-01",to_date="2019-10-30").items():
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

I used the above code to get the hashtag consists of `#adidasFR` but I am getting the past one week data.

I tried all the StackOverflow answer, even though I am getting the past one-week data tweets.

i am getting the tweets from `25-12-2019` to `01-01-2020`, but i want the tweets from `01-10-2019` to `30-10-2019`

Comment: _"I am getting the past one week data"_ -- what exactly does that mean? You are searching posts from October so you should be getting "past two months" data. Please give an example and/or list exact results' characteristics that are off and what you expected instead.

Comment: i am getting the tweets from 25-12-2019 to 01-01-2020, but i want the tweets from 01-10-2019 to 30-10-2019

Comment: There are no such parameters "from_date" and "to_date" in http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.8.0/api.html#API.search

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev that dupe and remark do not apply here. There is a fresh branch with `premium-search`, https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/branches, which is unlikely in the main docs.

Comment: @Siva have you installed the correct branch as described here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1175#issuecomment-552457039

Comment: @tevemadar then the OP should specify what code they are using! The default expectation is the latest release.

Comment: And also specify anything else unusual -- e.g. some premium subscription plan on their account if that makes a difference.